# Freeze minutes at "00" in the format input = datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input = datetime-local.
I should set the minutes for all hours to "00" and not make them selectable from the menu. Do you know how I can do it?
I show you my code below.

```html
<input id="data_inizio" name="data_inizio" class="input" type="datetime-local"  min="T09:00" max="17:30"  placeholder=" "/>
```

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
var time = "T09:00";
var datetime = today + time;
document.getElementsByName("data_inizio")[0].setAttribute('min', datetime);
```

I can't use step, but I want to default to "00" for minutes.

```js
       var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
        var time = "T09:00";
        var datetime= today + time;
        document.getElementsByName("data_inizio")[0].setAttribute('min', datetime);
```

```html
<input id="data_inizio" name="data_inizio" class="input" type="datetime-local"  min="09:00" max="17:30"  placeholder=" " />
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) -> Please use a code-block (or in this case a snippet would also work) and some more white-space (line breaks) to increase the readability of your question.

Comment: that snippet has an error... you have not added an input element `data_fine`

Comment: yes, I corrected

Comment: @LuigiEsposito why can't you use the `step` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try mangling the submitted date yourself in a similar fashion to the initial `split` to separate the date constituent parts. Substitute your own value in for minutes and rebuild a new datestring value

```js
const pad=(i)=>( parseInt(i)<10 ) ? '0' + parseInt(i) : parseInt(i);

let today=new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
let time='T09:00';

let input=document.querySelector('input[name="data_inizio"][type="datetime-local"]');
    input.setAttribute('min', today + time );
    input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
      let [ date, time ]=this.value.split('T')
      let [ hrs, mins ]=time.split(':');
      mins=0;
      
      let newdate=[ date, [ pad(hrs), pad(mins) ].join(':') ].join('T');
      input.value=newdate
    });
```

```css
label{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:1rem;
}
```

```html
<label>Start: <input name="data_inizio" class="input" type="datetime-local" min="09:00" max="17:30" /></label>
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide the choice of minutes?

Comment: I do not believe that there is